# Не срабатывает условия для вывода или ввода данных

Tags: android, kotlin, activity, android-shared-preferences

В первом запуске shared preference ничего не должно быть и выводиться null. Я все проверила в логах, но условие не срабатывает.
Вот как я сохраняю

```
fun save(value: String, key: String) {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
        editor.apply {
            putString(key, value)
        }.apply()
    }
```

Как вывожу

```
 fun load(key: String): String? {
        val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("shared", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val value = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null)
        return value
    }
```

И как проверяю

```
fun getProfile() {
        if (load("userName") != null){
            val name = load("userName")
            Log.i("TAG", name.toString())
            this.name.text = name.toString()
        }
        else{
            Log.i("TAGElLSE", this.editText.text.toString())
            if (this.editText.text.isNotEmpty()){
                save(editText.text.toString(), "userName")
                this.name.text = load("userName")
                Log.i("TAGElse", load("userName").toString())
            }
        }
    }
```

Возможно из-за того что editText в другом активити

Comment: что значит что поле в другой активности? по логике вы можете обращаться к памяти приложения отовсюду

Comment: по логике да, я инициализировала editText вот так не знаю насколько это правильно  
 actionbar = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_setting, null);                                  editText = actionbar.findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)

Comment: приложите пожалуйста как вы этот виджет инициализировали, и распишите что откуда вы пишете и кто вызывает метод save

Comment: Я вызываю метод save, load, getProfile в MainActivity, а editText находиться в Setting это тоже активити

Comment: ну сохранять нужно как-бы там где и пишите) считывать можно где угодно, либо вынесите в отдельный класс эти методы и дергайте когда вам нужно будет

Comment: спасибо, попробую